Using Jetpack Compose in OverlayPlugin
I am trying to customise the System UI Navigation Bar using Jetpack Compose. Unlike ordinary applications which have access to Activity or Fragments, the navigation bar is modified by implementing the OverlayPlugin(interface link) and declaring it in the AndroidManifest.xml file (code below taken from this link) as a Service.
<service android:name=".SampleOverlayPlugin"
    android:label="@string/plugin_label"
    android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.systemui.action.PLUGIN_OVERLAY" />
</intent-filter>

when using the context provided, I get the following error:
"Tried to access the API:ViewConfiguration which needs to have proper configuration from a non-UI
Context:com.android.documentsui.DocumentsApplication@608ad35 The API:ViewConfiguration needs a proper configuration. Use UI contexts such as an activity or a context created via createWindowContext(Display, int, Bundle) or  createConfigurationContext(Configuration) with a proper configuration.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access the API:ViewConfiguration which needs to have proper configuration from a non-UI Context:com.android.documentsui.DocumentsApplication@608ad35".
I have tried solutions similar to:

InputMethodService with Jetpack Compose - ComposeView causes: Composed into the View which doesn't propagate ViewTreeLifecycleOwner
https://www.techyourchance.com/jetpack-compose-inside-android-service/

but to no avail.

I am posting a possible solution with a reference in case it can assist someone else in the future.
https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/hmi/car_ui/plugins#jetpack_compose
The code snippet is copied from the link above in case the hyperlink is modified in the future.
class ComposeViewWithLifecycle @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),
    LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner, SavedStateRegistryOwner {

  private val lifeCycle = LifecycleRegistry(this)
  private val modelStore = ViewModelStore()
  private val savedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)
  private var composeView: ComposeView? = null
  private var content = @Composable {}

  init {
    ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, this)
    ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(this, this)
    ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(this, this)
    compositionContext = createCompositionContext()
  }

  fun setContent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    this.content = content
    composeView?.setContent(content)
  }

  override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
    return lifeCycle
  }

  override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
    return modelStore
  }

  override fun getSavedStateRegistry(): SavedStateRegistry {
    return savedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
  }

  override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    savedStateRegistryController.performRestore(Bundle())
    lifeCycle.currentState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
    composeView = ComposeView(context)
    composeView?.setContent(content)
    addView(composeView, LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    lifeCycle.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
    modelStore.clear()
    removeAllViews()
    composeView = null
  }

  // Exact copy of View.createCompositionContext() in androidx's WindowRecomposer.android.kt
  private fun createCompositionContext(): CompositionContext {
    val currentThreadContext = AndroidUiDispatcher.CurrentThread
    val pausableClock = currentThreadContext[MonotonicFrameClock]?.let {
      PausableMonotonicFrameClock(it).apply { pause() }
    }
    val contextWithClock = currentThreadContext + (pausableClock ?: EmptyCoroutineContext)
    val recomposer = Recomposer(contextWithClock)
    val runRecomposeScope = CoroutineScope(contextWithClock)
    val viewTreeLifecycleOwner = checkNotNull(ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(this)) {
      "ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from $this"
    }
    viewTreeLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(
      LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        @Suppress("NON_EXHAUSTIVE_WHEN")
        when (event) {
          Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE ->
            // Undispatched launch since we've configured this scope
            // to be on the UI thread
            runRecomposeScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
              recomposer.runRecomposeAndApplyChanges()
            }
          Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> pausableClock?.resume()
          Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> pausableClock?.pause()
          Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> {
            recomposer.cancel()
          }
        }
      }
    )
    return recomposer
  }

//  TODO: ComposeViewWithLifecycle should handle saving state and other lifecycle things
//  override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
//    val superState = super.onSaveInstanceState()
//    val bundle = Bundle()
//    savedStateRegistryController.performSave(bundle)
//  }
}

